# PyQt Send a signal from a class (sub-window) back to the MainWindow (class)

Tags: python, pyqt

How can I send a signal from my class ScanQrCode() back to the calss MainDialog()? I am using Python 2.7 and PyQt with windows generated by QtDesigner4.
I did manage to send the signal from within the class ScanQrCode() to a receiving function also within the class. However the signal gets lost when I try to receive it by another class MainDialog() but in the same file

```
class ScanQrCode( QtGui.QDialog, Ui_ScanQrCode ):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()    

    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( ScanQrCode, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setupUi( self ) 
        self.pushButton_Scan.clicked.connect( self.scan )         
    # End of __init__    

    def scan( self ):
        print 'Scanning'
        # Place holder for the functionality to scan the QR code
        self.lineEdit_QrCode.setText( "QR-123456789" ) # Dummy QR code
        if ( not self.signalsBlocked() ):
            print 'emit trigger'
            self.trigger.emit()
    # End of sub-function scan
# End of class ScanQrCode

class MainDialog( QtGui.QMainWindow, agpt_gui.Ui_MainWindow ):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( MainDialog, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setupUi( self )          
        self.connectActions()
        self.windowScanQrCode = None

        #Define threads
        self.thread = ScanQrCode()
        self.thread.trigger.connect( self.updateQrCode )
    # end of __init__

    def main( self ):
        self.show()  

    def connectActions( self ):
        # Define the connection from button to function
        self.pushButton_ScanQrCode.clicked.connect( self.scanQrCode ) 
        self.pushButton_Exit.clicked.connect( self.exit )
    # End of sub-function connectActions


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def updateQrCode( self ):
        """
        Update the new scanned QR code in the main window
        """
        print 'Update QR code'
        self.lineEdit_QrCode.setText("123456789")
    # End of sub-function updateQrCode

    def scanQrCode( self ):
        if self.windowScanQrCode is None:
            self.windowScanQrCode = ScanQrCode( self )  
        self.windowScanQrCode.show()
    # End of sub-function scanQrCode
# End of class MainDialog
```

There is no error. Simply the main window does not update.
I think in principle the Signal and connect are working but there must be something missing which I can not see.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ScanQrCode` instance that you show (`windowScanQrCode`) never has its `trigger` signal hooked up to `updateQrCode`. Meanwhile, the `ScanQrCode` instance that you hook up properly (`thread`) is never shown.

The simplest solution is to delete the method `scanQrCode` and replace the line

```
self.pushButton_ScanQrCode.clicked.connect( self.scanQrCode )
```

with the line

```
self.pushButton_ScanQrCode.clicked.connect( self.thread.show )
```

and then call `connectActions()` after you define `thread`.